# Differences between 3G and 3GS iphone?

Tags: iphone, background-process

I know it is a silly question. But, i cant gather more informations about this. I want to know the difference between 3G and 3GS iphones. Mainly is iphone 3G supporting Background process, Multitasking and Push Notification features? Can any one clarify my question? Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone 3G:

- Background processes: NO
- Multitasking: NO
- Push Notifications: YES

iPhone 3G S (running iOS 4+):

- Background processes: YES
- Multitasking: YES
- Push Notifications: YES

Comment: Thanks Mr.hypercrypt for quick response and spend your valuable time with me. But, i have one 3G iphone for testing, it's ios version 4.2.1, when i click the home button app going to background. It is possible? Please help me. If my question is silly means forgive me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is going to the background, and it isn't just that the app is saving its state before quitting?

Comment: In *iPhone 3G* if you press the *Home* key the app will be terminated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great response. I can accept your answer by after 5 minutes. I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to both EmptyStack,Amorya for quick response.Ya the app is going to background when i click the home button. Again i can get the app from background. This 3G mobile ios version is 4.2.1, i think because of this app going to background(Home button click).